# Vertical scrollbar causes div not to stretch to available space

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I want the whole of the inner container to be horizontally scrollable if there is not enough space. The top div inside the inner container (green part) should be vertically scrollable if there is not enough vertical space available.

The problem I'm running into is once I set the vertical scroll on the `topDiv`, it actually limits the width of that div. When you scroll horizontally you will see that there is space available but it is not filled up. The solution I'm looking for should stretch the green part.

```css
.outerContainer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.innerContainer {
  overflow: auto hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: stretch space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.topDiv {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}

.bottomDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
}

.innerDiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="topDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomDiv">This should always be visible</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeroenwallaeys/pen/KKGxzgZ)

I tried to force the width of the `topDiv` by setting it to 100%, but that did nothing. It only changes when setting it with a certain amount of pixels (which is not a viable solution).

Answer (score -1):

You can try wrapping `bottomDiv` in another div which has `overflow: auto`. Not sure if this works for you but it might point you in the right direction :)

```css
.outerContainer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.innerContainer {
  overflow: auto hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: stretch space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.topDiv {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}

.bottomDivWrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.bottomDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
}

.innerDiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="topDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
      <div class="innerDiv">Some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomDivWrapper">
      <div class="bottomDiv">This should always be visible</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem then is that you horizontally scroll the bottom div separately from the top one, which I'm afraid is not what I'm looking for.